# Find cities within a circle with Here.com API

Tags: geocoding, here-api

I need to find the cities (municipality) in a circle around a point, the only way I found to do that is to search for "city-hall" (800-8100-0163). I use with `curl` from `php` to retrieve the `json` result.

```
https://browse.search.hereapi.com/v1/browse?at={$coords}&in=circle:{$coords};r={$raggio}&lang=it&categories=800-8100-0163&limit=100&apiKey=<apiKey>
```

but some cities are missing in the result even if there's a city-hall in there so I think it's the wrong way to do that.

So my question is: is there a better way to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your request should be other.

If you search in [Places Category System](https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/dev_guide/topics/place_categories/places-category-system.html) then should be parameter cat=800-8100-0163 and parameter (category system) should be cs=pds

Then request will look like: https://places.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/browse?in=42.2722%2C13.3917%3Br%3D180718&cat=800-8100-0163&size=100&cs=pds&Accept-Language=it-It%2Cit%3Bq%3D0.9%2Cru-RU%3Bq%3D0.8%2Cru%3Bq%3D0.7%2Cde-DE%3Bq%3D0.6%2Cde%3Bq%3D0.5&app_id=WvHj2YKdvDQaKq1ZWCwL&app_code=W-ENnB-UBLqwG7sEhqyLMQ